# How to make multiple AJAX requests with a for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm practicing the Star Wars API (SWAPI) and I'm trying to print the names of all the planets. However, the planet data is contained among different pages, so how would I make multiple AJAX requests to print all of the data? Here's what I have:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var link = 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/';
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var planets = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var responseHTML = '<p>';
            for (i in planets.results) {
                responseHTML += planets.results[i].name;
            }
            responseHTML += planets.results[1];
            responseHTML += '</p>';
            //console.log(planets.results.length);
        }
        document.querySelector('main').innerHTML = responseHTML;
    };
    xhr.open('GET', link);
    xhr.send();
    link += '?page=' + i;
}
```

Comment: The Web API should have a method like getAllPlanets().

Comment: @shane harper, see the answer below, should do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a loop I would use a recursive function. The reason for this is that it will wait for the request to be returned before the next request is triggered. If you use a loop the results may not come back in the order you expect.

Also, you can take advantage of [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to make the request. `fetch` is the more modern way to make AJAX requests.

See code example below.

```js
// set index to zero
let index = 0;

const performAjaxRequest = index => {
  // fetch request will only be made if index is less than 7
  if (index < 7) {
    // increase index by one below using index++
    // first time code runs it will be 1, second time 2, third time 3...
    // this gives the same effect as using a loop
    index++;

    // make fetch call and add index to the url
    fetch(`https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=${index}`).then(res => {
       return res.json();
    }).then(res => {

       // this loop is to display each country from the response on the screen
       for (var i = 0; i < res.results.length; i++) {
         document.body.append(res.results[i].name + ', ');
       }
       // below is the key and what makes this a recursive function. 
       // The function calls itself.
       // After the response has been received from the API the function is 
       // called again which which will trigger another fetch request
       performAjaxRequest(index);
    })
  }
}

// trigger initial invocation of the function
performAjaxRequest(index);
```

Comment: Gotcha - I'm mainly using SWAPI to work on my AJAX skills (still on the elusive job hunt). So you recommend learning fetch to make AJAX requests instead of what I would assume be the older way? Two more questions - 1) Why are you calling the performAjaxRequest function after the for loop? and 2) What is the ${index} in the url? I know it's for the new page number but still need to wrap my head around it.

Comment: ah ok, so firstly, yes I would learn `fetch` instead. As long as you are aware that there is an 'older' way then I think use `fetch`, it is kind of what everyone uses :-D. Secondly, the `for` loop is nothing to do with the AJAX call, it is just to loop through the `planets` as the response from SWAPI has the `planets` in an array. The ${index} is a new javascript feature that allows you to pass variables into strings. So it is the same as `'http://swapi.com' + index`. The difference is that you use ticks instead of quotes. And the feature is called called template strings. All make sense?

Comment: More details on the string literals here - Details here - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

Comment: oh and for a job hunt I would use `fetch`, I think it would show you are more up to date with current JS practices, although there are probably many on here that would disagree with me :-D

Comment: Makes more sense haha - def gonna use fetch to impress my future employers haha. Also, why did you have to call the function again after the for loop? Just trying to piece it all together haha.

Comment: So again, the loop isn't making the `fetch` request, that is just to display the countries. I call the function again as that is what a recursive function does, it calls itself. So in this case I call the function over and over until the index is `7`, which means the `fetch` call gets made 7 times, as it is within the `performAjaxRequest` function. Also, it is called once at the bottom of the whole snippet to trigger the function, which then starts calling itself. Make sense? Lots of info there and is tough to follow when you're starting out :-D

Comment: updated the code with comments :-) Also, here is a good page with a link to lots of APIS you could use to practice - https://github.com/toddmotto/public-apis

Comment: Got it - sorry to have you repeat yourself - it makes sense to me now. And I'll definitely check out the APIs - thanks!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but i might need your help again with another question I just posted haha.

Comment: I saw that someone already answered. Good work though, just remember whatever name you give the argument in the `then` part must be the same in the next part. Also, I saw the guy said look at jQuery's `$.get()` method. This will do the same thing as `fetch` but just means you will also have to bring in jquery to your project, so if I was you I would stick to learning how `fetch` works and then move on. There are so many libraries that allow you to do the same thing in js that devs get overwhelmed, it is what javascript fatigue is if you have heard of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.checkbox:checkbox:checked').each(function (index, element) {
  $.ajax({
  // your ajax code
  });
});
```

Above code is for list of checkbox which are checked and you're pushing data of each checked box

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you'll never know when you are going to finish due to they are asynchronous requests, what I usually do with this kind of problem is to make recursive functions so the answer will call same function with different parameter for make the next request.

I considered that you wanted to save in "responseHTML" the answer of all of those requests.
Something like this:

```
var link = 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/';
var responseHTML = "";
makeRequest(1,7,link);

function makeRequest(index,max,link)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var planets = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            responseHTML += '<p>';
            for (i in planets.results) {
                responseHTML += planets.results[i].name;
            }
            responseHTML += planets.results[1];
            responseHTML += '</p>';
            //console.log(planets.results.length);
        }

        if(index<=max)
        {
            link += '?page=' + i;
            index++;
            makeRequest(index++,max,link);
        }
        else
        {
            //This means I finished so I put the responseHTML and finish the code.
            document.querySelector('main').innerHTML = responseHTML;
        }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', link);
    xhr.send();
}
```